# Help about SQLite iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite, fmdb

I am developing iphone aplication is which i have 5 sqlite tables. First we set the database path & database name. In my case how can i do that? I know how to do this for 1 db table. how can i do for 5 tables? should i create 5 different dbName variables & 1 dbPath variable common to all? I am stuck here. I am using SQLite3 not the FMDB. Somehow i can't use FMDB. Also if anyone have FMDB sample application / tutorial except which is provided with FMDB (fmdb.m) please give me link to the same. That will be helpful & appreciated.  Please help me friends.

Answer (score 1):

You can create many tables in sqlite.  But First when you run your application you need to copy your Database to the phone application.  Than you can get the data from that specific table depending on the use.